# How to start project for an autonomous vehicle

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I think this is not the common way of questions asked here but I just give it a try.
I am working at a project in which a car should autonomous drive in a predefined map and with predefined endposition. This should be solved with the use of ROS and Gazebo (for now i guess it is not that important that it is really a car - it could also be an example robot or whatever).
My problem here is that i can't find a suitable example project to get started with this. So I am pretty unsure how to launch such a project.

For now I am using ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Can you give me an outline or some examples how you could start with such a project?

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191802/how-to-start-project-for-an-autonomous-vehicle/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The self-driving car team at the University of Texas ran ROS on their self-driving car for quite a while before it was retired in 2013. Most of their work is publicly available and documented on the ROS wiki.

http://www.ros.org/news/2010/03/robots-using-ros-marvin-autonomous-car.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-09-04**:
I already saw this, but there work is not compatible to indigo am I wrong?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-05**:
In general, older ROS packages should work with newer versions of ROS. In any case, it's better than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the turtlebots have use the navigation stack to achieve something like you describe.

I currently can't access the ros wiki, but there is a list of available packages with a short descripton. See if you can find something that suits your needs.
I never used the navigation features, but I think there were some fairly detailed tutorials for the turtlebot.

TL;DR: I think it's possible, google for "ROS turtlebot navigation"

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-09-04**:
Same here:

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator

No Indigo support isn't it?

---

Oh there is branch for indigo but no tutorials